# What is "Drift" in context of transformation concatenation?

Tags: computer-vision, transform

My lecturer talked about transformation concatenation and he mentioned the "Drift" problem and that "bundle adjustment" may solve it. Since I could not find any information on it online, I have the following questions regarding it:

- What is the proper definition of "Drift" and how this "error" occurs?
- How "bundle adjustment" solves this problem?

Comment: I'm really missing a lot of context here. Let's start with: What kind of transformation? Of what?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My lecturer didn't explain much. Said "transformation". He did explain it in the context of - if you have image A with a ball, image B with that ball and a table and image C with that table, then you don't need to combine the images A-B-C. You can use the transformation concatenation and just do A-C.

Comment: @that's already much more context than you originally gave, still not enough to go on, sadly. So, what's the title of the lecture you're hearing? Maybe there's a chapter title? "transformation" is really a broader term than you seem to think it is!